# Unity how to check if two sprites are the same

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello I'm creating an orb game on unity, I'm looking to find out how to see if the two sprites match and the the orb will successfully destroy, if the player is a different orb compared to the spawned orb the player will die. Im struggling on the part where I compare the sprite renderers :/ 
player (hand in my case):

```
public Transform mHandMesh;

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{
    mHandMesh.position = Vector3.Lerp(mHandMesh.position, transform.position, Time.deltaTime * 15.0f);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (!collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Orb"))
    {
        return;
    }

    Orb orb = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Orb>();
    StartCoroutine(orb.Pop());
}
```

}

Orb:

```
public IEnumerator Pop()
    {
        mSpriteRenderer.sprite = mPopSprite;
        StopCoroutine(mCurrentChanger);
        mMovementDirection = Vector3.zero;
        ScoreScript.scoreValue += 1;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        transform.position = mOrbManager.GetPlanePosition();

        mSpriteRenderer.sprite = mOrbSprite;
        mCurrentChanger = StartCoroutine(DirectionChanger());

    }
```

[image]

Comment: I think you've already done it, if I read your question correctly. If you tag your Player with the "Player" tag and all other Orbs with the "Orb" tag then your code should work without figuring out if Sprites are the same.  Assuming you have 1 Player.

Comment: Yes the tags work, this is a voice recognition game, lets say for an instance the player orb is a Water orb, it can only destroy water orbs that are instantiated by the orb manager, and if it's not the same sprite orb the player orb will destroy itself.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind and cant see that I have it done D: , pretty sure I don't, cant wrap my head around how to compare sprites instead of tags

Comment: You should be able to compare sprites with `SpriteRender.sprite`